# I would like to process semi-structured text. Can machine learning be used?

Tags: machine-learning

I have many emails that I would like to extract data from. The emails contain data but in different formats.

The below example contains data about a request for a shipment:

```
Account: SugarHigh Inc
Qty: 1,000 Tons Sugar
Date: 9 - 15 July
From: NY
To: IL
```

I would like to extract the above into the following format:

```
Account        Quantity     Product     FromDate     ToDate     From     To
-------        --------     -------     --------     ------     ----     --
SugarHigh Inc  1000         Sugar       9 July       15 July    NY       IL
```

The same request can arrive in a different format.For example:

```
Acc: SugarHigh Inc
Qty/Date: 1,000 Tons Sugar/9 - 15 July
From/To: NY/IL
```

Some requests can even have more or less fields or describe things differently.

Can machine learning be used in assisting to extract this data fully/partially? If so what type of algorithms/models exist for this type of problem? I am assuming I might also need to use some type of dictionary for known words such as products or locations.

Comment: This may be off topic.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Machine learning is very much on-topic here. If there's another objection, please spell it out what it is.

Comment: I just think it may be more suitable for StackOverflow which I mention in my vote to close.

Comment: @Michael Chernick Thanks for stating your view, but the OP can't see that reasoning. There isn't a reproducible code example here, so even if it were seen to be about programming, it's not suitable for Stack Overflow. SO moderators and active users have repeatedly flagged that they (we in my case) don't want questions to be migrated if they are not up to SO standards. However, I see this as being too broad, so agree on a vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need some sequence learner (on word level), e.g. CRF or RNN, that either outputs a tag or a "null" symbol at each word, where the tag would represent a type of class you want and "null" would mean still inside the last tag. Given appropriately tagged training data you can then just treat it as a supervised classification problem.

Take for example:

```
Account: SugarHigh Inc Qty: 1,000 Tons Sugar Date: 9 - 15 July From: NY To: IL
```

The corresponding labeling would be:

```
ACCOUNT 0 0 QUANTITY 0 0 PRODUCT DATE 0 0 0 0 FROM 0 TO 0
```

Of course the textual labels are representing numbers as given by a softmax layer, e.g. ACCOUNT = 1.

I published a paper nearly ten years ago about something very similar for parsing bibliographical meta-data with probabilistic finite state transducers. It could help to illuminate the overall problem, although I'd rather use something like LSTMs nowadays. See here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/61d5/37dffd719ee98bd6871564d924dd38c9a075.pdf